# Get Value Of Id From array

Tags: php, mysql

I have array of `$user = wp_get_current_user();`. When I print this it will show like

```
WP_User Object
(
    [data] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 169 // I wanted the Value of ID
            [user_login] => madhuri@gmail.com
            [user_pass] => $P$BN2ibVoWTXB1DIsdcTnpVV03DBz8od0
            [user_nicename] => madhurigmail-com
            [user_email] => madhuri@gmail.com
            [user_url] => 
            [user_registered] => 2015-11-17 09:54:57
            [user_activation_key] => 
            [user_status] => 0
            [display_name] => Madhuri Kashid
            [latitude] => 
            [longitude] => 
            [role] => 
        )
```

I wanted the value of ID only.
i wanted the Store value of ID into the `$UserId`
Thanks in advance

Comment: use `$UserId = $user->data->ID`

Comment: @jitendrapurohit Post this as answer.

Comment: @HappyCoder posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting object not array

Try

```
$UserId = $user->data->ID;
```

Comment: Thanks So Much @Hassaan

Comment: @shankar I'm glad it works for you. Please tick mark my answer if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Following my comment, to access the attribute inside the object, use '->' operator.

```
$UserId = $user->data->ID;
```

Comment: This is an Object. Hence, $UserId = $user->data->ID;

Comment: what change does this make ?

Answer (score 0):

This is an Object. Hence, `$UserId = $user->data->ID;`
If you want to access it as an array, first type cast it into an array,
`$array   = (array) $user;$user_id = $array['data']['ID'];`